# Plot and compare difference among barplots

Tags: r

I have a piece of work is to barplot several data on the same graph and visually distinguish the difference among them. Below is my code. let say we plot data[4] and data[3]. On the right hand side of the intersection of the linear line with x-axis, data[4] has lower slope than data[3]. Meanwhile, on the left hand side, data[4] has higher slope than data[3]. So, the problem appears to the right hand side, if I barplot the data[4] first, then data[3]; the data[3] will overwrite the existing data[4]'s barplot. The left hand side is OK for me, I can visually distinguish the difference area btw 2 plots...
Any suggestions woulb be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

```
############################################################
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")
dev.off()

#number of barplot
n=4

#plotting order, from the graph with lowest slope to highest slope
case = seq(4,1,-1)
case
##########
data = matrix(
  0,# the data elements
  nrow=n,              # number of rows = #row of dataset
  ncol=64,              # number of columns of wji = #row of dataset
  byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows 

# ############################################################
# draw empty graph
par(new=TRUE)
plot(0,0,type = "b", xlim=c(0,64), ylim=c(-8,8),xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
abline(a=0,b=0,v=0)

############################################################
# from lighter to darker when index increases
color_range<-gray.colors(n+1,start=1,end=0)
color_range


n=4
##########
data = matrix(
  0,# the data elements
  nrow=n,              # number of rows = #row of dataset
  ncol=64,              # number of columns of wji = #row of dataset
  byrow = TRUE)   
data[1,]=seq(0,0,length.out=64);data[1,]
data[2,]=seq(-6,6,length.out=64);data[2,]
data[3,]=seq(-7,5,length.out=64);data[3,]
data[4,]=seq(-8,4,length.out=64);data[4,]

for (n in case){
  data_plot <- data[n,]
  data_plot    
  #===========

  readline(prompt = "Pause. Press <Enter> to continue...")

  barplot(data_plot,  col = color_range[n], add=T, density=-1)

  readline(prompt = "Pause. Press <Enter> to continue...")

  #save each plot into file
  file_ext="jpg"
  output_file = paste("plot_with_n_", n,file_ext, sep = ".")
  dev.copy(jpeg,filename=output_file);
  dev.off()

}#end for
```

[image]
[image]

data[4] (see plot_with_n_.4.jpg)
data[3] (see plot_with_n_.3.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps with ggplot? I think that transparancy is important here (so you get everything visible). However, together with a grey scale this might still not be as clear as hoped for...

```
n=4
data = matrix(
0,# the data elements
nrow=n,              # number of rows = #row of dataset
ncol=64,              # number of columns of wji = #row of dataset
byrow = TRUE)   
data[1,]=seq(0,0,length.out=64);data[1,]
data[2,]=seq(-6,6,length.out=64);data[2,]
data[3,]=seq(-7,5,length.out=64);data[3,]
data[4,]=seq(-8,4,length.out=64);data[4,]

#retransform data so it can be used easily with ggplot
mydata=melt(data.frame(t(data)))
mydata$x=1:ncol(data)

color_range<-gray.colors(n+1,start=1,end=0)

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",alpha=0.3,color="black",position=position_dodge(width = 0),width=4) +  # dodged to avoid stacking, width=0 to have bars at same X and width=4 (objective) to have bars touching for a nicer look
  scale_fill_manual(values=color_range)+
  theme_classic()+  # this and the next two lines to make it look like your plot
  ylab("y")+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The graph looks beautiful with ggplot. However, I doubt about the way you are plotting data  . For example, in my data, at x=0, there is no value y which is -20 like your graph, and also at x=64, y cannot equal to +15. You can reasonably see that my data has ylim =c(-8,6). Also, the shape of the graph for each data[i], as we move i=4, 3, 2, 1, has lower slope on the right hand side of the intersection, and higher slope/angle on the  left side . For all those reasons, I am afraid you are plotting completely different graph. Would u pls double check yr plotting data?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I forgot 2 parameters. It's adapted now and I hope this works as you wanted it to. So now the transparency is indeed the key to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your nice support. The right hand side is ok. However, the left hand side's colors are not consistent with its part on the right hand side. Let say data[4]=seq(-8,4,length.out=64), the right hand side has darkest color (x,y)=(64,4) while the left hand side at (x,y)=(1,-8) it has "ligher" color. I want to plot each data[i] by one distinguish color, so that I can compare the different among them. Would you please check your solution again?

Comment: The plot is correct, but seems wrong because of the tansaprency. When transparent light greys are put on top of each other, they look dark. If you play around with alpha (0=100% transparent, 1=normal) you'll see. You can look at it with colors as well. A second option is by splitting geom_bar, for postive or negative values or for every layer (e.g. dat[4]), like this:
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(data=mydata[mydata$value<0,],stat="identity",alpha=1,color="black",position=position_dodge(width = 0),width=3) + ...